# Show that the matrix $A$ is invertible for all values of $\theta$.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I know how to find $A^{-1}$ with multiply the matrix with identity matrix

but I don't understand how to prove that the matrix s invertible for all values of theta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Compute its determinant; show that no matter what $\theta$ is, it is non-zero.

**Hint #2:** it is 1.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: You can check that for this kind of matrices the inverse is the transpose
$$A^{-1}=A^{t}$$